# i have a lot of space on my phone but my apps say it still needs a memory card?

Tags: external-sd, sd-card

why is it that when I run an app it says I need an sd card? even though I have 6 gb available on my phone still??

Comment: Well it depends on what app you are talking about. It is mostly an app error, but also do tell your android version.

Comment: 1) Is the issue specific to an app or are all the apps behaving in this way? 2) Which device is it and which Android version is it running? 3) Screenshot(s) can also do good here. There is scarcity of details, making the question eligible for being unclear.

Answer (score 1):

Need more details before proper answer can be made for your device Alix

The name of your Android device and anything else related to the issues you're device is having will make answers more on point. That being stated the following are things I've noted that can cause issues with installing apps and the *fixes* I've used.

---

I've had issues with both internal and SD memory reporting full when trying to install apps when a file browser reports enough space when the `LOST.DIR` directory gets full of rescued data bits. This folder can usually have it's contence deleted without causing issues and will free up space that the system keeps in *limbo*.

Alternitively the apps you maybe trying to install may require that an exteral SD card be present for saving the larger files seperate from your internal storage.

Yet another alternitive is that the app's developer has coded the path to external storage in such a way that your device doesn't reconize the file path. Rare but it does happen when a device has odd directory paths or links not set properly.

And the other thing that maybe causing confusion is that Androids setup internal partitions to split memory for system apps and user apps. And the market app as well as google's many sub-system apps will eat nearly 100MBs of space on thier own within this partition.

---

Things I've done to fix similar issues :

~ Downgrade google's apps back to stock; found in each apps' setting screen from your app setings screen

~ Whipe caches and stored data from apps; there are cache cleaners on the market as well as options within custom recoveries to preform cache whipes. Custom recovery requires root/Super User permissions.

~ Root the device and modify memory partitions such that more is avalable for user apps and processes.

~ Root the device and remove *bloot ware* ie stock Mail app and GMail app and any other apps that wouldn't let me remove'em otherwise.

~ Lastly I've also had to compleatly wipe all data (deletes everything) from the device in order to free up odd sectors that seem to have gotten stuck between 1&0 :-( ...

---

Comment: Hi! When you post an answer to a question, the author of the latter will always be notified, so you don't have to use @ in the answers. It also doesn't work  when mentioned in answers. It is meant for comments. See its restriction and usage: http://android.stackexchange.com/editing-help#comment-formatting

Comment: Wups, kinda use to forum posting on Q&A sites. I've corrected the '@' sign; thank you Firelord for the link, I'll make good use of it :-D